# Representation in state-space of a system with ideal and real differentiating links in feedback

Tags: dynamic, control-systems, self-study

There are two systems in the state space with an ideal and a real differentiator.

[image]

[image]

For the first system, the code in Mathematica is as follows.

```
nsys = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[
  x'[t] == D[Power[x[t], 2], t] + 0.01 Sin[10 t], x[t], u[t], x[t], t]
Plot[Evaluate@OutputResponse[{nsys, 1}, 0, {t, 0, 20}], {t, 0, 20}]
```

What will the code look like for receiving the output signal if instead of the ideal differentiator in feedback the real differentiator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations can be constructed from the block diagram and then directly passed to [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).

```
eqns = {x'[t] == u[t] + f[t], f'[t] + f[t] == D[Power[x[t], 2], t]} /. u[t] -> 0.01 Sin[10 t];
x[t] /. NDSolve[Join[%, {x[0] == 0.5, f[0] == 0}], {x[t], f[t]}, {t, 0, 5}];
p1 = Plot[%, {t, 0, 5}];
```

Or we can use [`SystemsConnectionsModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsConnectionsModel.html) to build the model and go from there.

```
add = TransferFunctionModel[{{1, 1}}, s];
int = TransferFunctionModel[1/s, s];
sq = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{}, u^2}, {}, u];
diff = TransferFunctionModel[s/(s + 1), s];
SystemsConnectionsModel[{add, int, sq, diff}, 
  {{1, 1} -> {2, 1}, {2, 1} -> {3, 1}, {3, 1} -> {4, 1}, {4, 1} -> {1, 2}}, 
  {{1, 1}}, {{2, 1}}] // SystemsModelMerge
p2 = Plot[Evaluate@OutputResponse[{%, {0.5, 0.5^2}}, 0.01 Sin[10 t], {t, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 5}];
```

> [image]

Both approaches should give the same result.

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

(The latter approach will not work for the ideal differentiator because [`NonlinearStateSpaceModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearStateSpaceModel.html) does not support descriptor systems yet.)

Comment: Dear Suba Thomas, the question arose: is it possible to write down the equation of the above systems in the form $x'=Ax+Bu$ (with one state-space variable, not two), or because of the differentiating links is impossible?

Comment: @AndySol You can get an affine representation using `AffineStateSpaceModel[eqns, {x[t], f[t]}, u[t], x[t], t]`. It will have two states and will be of the form $x'=a(x)+b(x).u$ . The second state comes from the pole in the denominator of the real differentiator. (`eqns = {x'[t] == u[t] + f[t], f'[t] + f[t] == D[Power[x[t], 2], t]}`)